# Global variables losing values at footer

Tags: crystal-reports, global-variables

I  have three global variables.  two loose their value when they hit a footer, but the other one does not, and I do not understand why.

1 group header

2 group header    (all 3 globals reset)

3 group header

detail (not displayed)

3 group footer    (values on globals set and displayed- see the functions below)

2 group footer    (attempt to sum all variables together)

1 group footer

when I attempt to sum the globals on 2 group footer, varCccCount is at zero and varFishCsvcCount is at zero, but Varothercount retains it's value.

Any suggestions?

---

```
global numbervar varCccCount;

whileprintingrecords;

if left({v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I},3)="CCC" then
// this is a CCC course and I want to count it
        if isnull (Maximum ({HR2TRA04.DATE1}, {v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I}))
            then
    // this CCC course has never been taken
            varCccCount:=varCccCount
            else
    // has this CCC course expired by the cut off date of the report?
            if {@Expires}<{?Cut-off Date} then varCccCount:=varCccCount else
        varCccCount:=varCccCount+1
  // this is not a ccc course, and I do not want to increase the CCC count
  else varCccCount:=varCccCount
```

---

```
global numbervar varFishCsvcCount;
whileprintingrecords;

if {v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I}='FISH' OR  {v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I}='CSVC' then


 // this is a FISH or CSVC course and I want to count it

        if isnull (Maximum ({HR2TRA04.DATE1}, {v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I}))
            then
    // this CCC course has never been taken.  do not increase
            varFishCsvcCount:=varFishCsvcCount
            else
    // has this CCC course expired by the cut off date of the report?
            if {@Expires}<{?Cut-off Date} then varFishCsvcCount:=varFishCsvcCount else
        varFishCsvcCount:=varFishCsvcCount+1

  // this is not a ccc course, and I do not want to increase the CCC count
  else varFishCsvcCount:=varFishCsvcCount
```

---

```
global numbervar varOtherCount;
whileprintingrecords;



if not({v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I} in ['CCC1','CCC2','CCC3','FISH','CSVC'])  Then
// This is NOT a course we are already counting somewhere else, so lets take a look at it

        if isnull (Maximum ({HR2TRA04.DATE1}, {v_EIS_EECoreCourseReq.COURSEID_I})) then
    // this course has never been taken
            varOtherCount:=varOtherCount
            else
                // has this course expired by the cut off date of the report?
                        if {@Expires}<{?Cut-off Date} then varOtherCount:=varOtherCount else
                    varOtherCount:=varOtherCount+1

// This is one of the courses we are already counting in another variable.  lets not count it
else varOtherCount:=varOtherCount
```

Comment: May be it is hitting the final `else` formula for first 2 formulas? have you checked the records and data?

Comment: in footer 3 they are pulling back their information and displaying correctly.  It's when I place them in footer 2 is when 2 of the 3 globals lose thier value while varOtherCount retains it's value.

Comment: it's my attempt to sum them all in footer 2 that I find the total is always the one that does not go to zero.  When I place the globals in footer 2 for display purposes, that is when I find they are zero.

Comment: try placing reset formulas in group header1